# Setup eslint with nuxt 3 using eslint nuxt module

Tags: nuxt.js, eslint, nuxtjs3

I am trying to setup eslint with Nuxt 3.2 but whenever I run my application it crashes. The following is my setup:

**package.json**

```
"devDependencies": {
    "@nuxt/eslint-config": "^0.1.1",
    "@nuxtjs/eslint-module": "^4.1.0",
    "eslint": "^8.43.0",
    "nuxt": "3.2.0"
  },
```

**.eslintrc**

```
{
    "extends": ["@nuxt/eslint-config"]
}
```

**nuxt.config.ts**

```
modules: ["@pinia/nuxt", "@nuxtjs/eslint-module"],
```

#### ERROR

```
ERROR  Cannot start nuxt:  Cannot find module 'ajv/dist/compile/codegen'                                                19:54:58
Require stack:
- C:\Work\Projects\lims-frontend\node_modules\ajv-keywords\dist\definitions\typeof.js
- C:\Work\Projects\lims-frontend\node_modules\ajv-keywords\dist\keywords\typeof.js
- C:\Work\Projects\lims-frontend\node_modules\ajv-keywords\dist\keywords\index.js
- C:\Work\Projects\lims-frontend\node_modules\ajv-keywords\dist\index.js
- C:\Work\Projects\lims-frontend\node_modules\schema-utils\dist\validate.js
- C:\Work\Projects\lims-frontend\node_modules\schema-utils\dist\index.js
- C:\Work\Projects\lims-frontend\node_modules\eslint-webpack-plugin\dist\options.js                                      19:54:34  
- C:\Work\Projects\lims-frontend\node_modules\eslint-webpack-plugin\dist\index.js

  Require stack:
  - node_modules\ajv-keywords\dist\definitions\typeof.js
  - node_modules\ajv-keywords\dist\keywords\typeof.js
  - node_modules\ajv-keywords\dist\keywords\index.js
  - node_modules\ajv-keywords\dist\index.js
  - node_modules\schema-utils\dist\validate.js
  - node_modules\schema-utils\dist\index.js
  - node_modules\eslint-webpack-plugin\dist\options.js
  - node_modules\eslint-webpack-plugin\dist\index.js
  at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:995:15)
  at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:841:27)
  at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1067:19)
  at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:103:18)
  at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules\ajv-keywords\dist\definitions\typeof.js:3:19)
  at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1165:14)
  at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1219:10)
  at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1043:32)
  at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:878:12)
  at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1067:19)
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a `.eslintrc` file in your root directory.

With JavaScript install `@nuxtjs/eslint-config` and add them to the eslintrc file with

```
{
  "extends": ["@nuxtjs/eslint-config"]
}
```

With TypeScript install `@nuxtjs/eslint-config-typescript` and add them to the eslintrc

```
{
  "extends": ["@nuxtjs/eslint-config-typescript"]
}
```

I think the problem is that you are using `@nuxt/eslint-config` instead of `@nuxtjs/eslint-config`.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are only suppose to use `@nuxtjs/eslint-module` in nuxt.config.ts, installed as a dev-dependency. It will run checks at build time.

`@nuxt/eslint-config` was recently released as the original package `@nuxtjs/eslint-config` was intended to be used for internal development only - [announced here](https://github.com/nuxt/eslint-config/issues/240).